# Как узнать, дёрнул ли мышь игрок влево или вправо по x(y не важен) (UNITY)

Tags: unity3d, mouse-event

Нужно узнать, в какую сторону дёрнулась мышь(лево, право) (верх и низ не учитывается). Не совсем понимаю, как это можно проверить. Вот отрезок кода:

```
using UnityEngine;


public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse2))
        {
 
                cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(cam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, cam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 1, cam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сравниваете положение мышки в предыдущем кадре и текущем.

```
float lastMouseX;  
void Start()
{
    lastMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x
}  
void Update()
{
    if (Input.mousePosition.x > lastMouseX)
    {
        // вправо
    }
    else if (Input.mousePosition.x < lastMouseX)
    {
        // влево
    }
    
    lastMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло.